# why is there no Output when IDEFICS based model is run on CUDA?

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, large-language-model, huggingface

I am using Huggingface based IDEFICS "idefics-9b" to instruct the model print a caption for the given image. I am using the code as mentioned in the section [1](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/tasks/idefics#image-guided-text-generation). Which means the model and the processor are on 'cuda' device. But When I run this code, the output doesn't contain anything after "Story" tag. But when I shift the model and processor on cpu, then there is a juicy story after the "Story" tag in the output.

The code is below:

```
checkpoint = "HuggingFaceM4/idefics-9b"
import torch

from transformers import IdeficsForVisionText2Text, AutoProcessor

processor = AutoProcessor.from_pretrained(checkpoint)

model = IdeficsForVisionText2Text.from_pretrained(checkpoint, torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16)

prompt = ["Instruction: Use the image to write a story. \n",

    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517086822157-2b0358e7684a?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2203&q=80",

    "Story: \n"]
model.to('cuda')
inputs = processor(prompt, return_tensors="pt").to("cuda")
bad_words_ids = processor.tokenizer(["<image>", "<fake_token_around_image>"], add_special_tokens=False).input_ids

generated_ids = model.generate(**inputs, num_beams=2, max_new_tokens=100)#, bad_words_ids=bad_words_ids)
generated_text = processor.batch_decode(generated_ids, skip_special_tokens=True)
print(generated_text[0])
```

It would be a big help to know what is the problem. Refer to the screenshot below.[image]

Comment: While I don't have solution for you, I was able to reproduce the behavior (no output on GPU, output on CPU) using your code and HF's provided code. Perhaps this is worth opening as an issue or asking on the [model discussion page](https://huggingface.co/HuggingFaceM4/idefics-9b/discussions)?

Comment: yeah i already have posted up this question there. I haven't got any response on it unfortunately. https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/why-is-there-no-output-when-idefics-based-model-is-run-on-cuda/67082

Comment: Just upgrade your transformers package. It was fixed with transformers 4.36.